# Micros online hand review. AKs from the SB

Tags: texas-hold-em, cash-game, no-limit, all-in

6 max Cash - Micros - Ignition

Hero on SB w/ ~150 BBs
UTG+1 calls w/ ~115 BBs
Button w/ ~115 BBs raises to 4xBB

Hero calls with A⋄K⋄
BB folds
UTG+1 calls

Flop comes 3⋄J⋄5♠
Table checks around.

Turn comes 5⋄
Hero bets 8x BBs (~, UTG+1 folds, Button calls.

River comes T⋄

Hero bets 16x BBs; Button shoves ~100BBs.

Do you call?

> I called it off he shows 5♥5♣ and felts me. Womp womp.
>  Reasoning:
>  * Raises pre then checks on the flop, leading me to think he might be chasing a lower flush or some KJo+ or some medium pocket pair and is afraid of the J and flush draw.
>  * He flats the turn leading me to believe he still might still be on some Q⋄J♠ esque hand.
>  * He shoves my bet on the river. I'm now sure that he's made his flush and am happy to call with the nut flush. The only reasonable thing I'm afraid of is him having 10s full.

Comment: If anyone knows how to keep cards hidden in the spoiler tags, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3):

That's a tough decision, but I would probably fold.

First off,  Flatting the turn should set off bells. A flush card falls that pairs the board,  and rather than raise and possibly have you fold a weaker hand, he's letting you continue to be the aggressor. Pretty standard at the micros.

The big all-in raise on the river pretty much screams that he has the nuts. You have to consider that all 3 pairs,  Js, 5s and 3s are in his range.

Comment: Did not say the hero did. Hero is in SB, so it has to be the villain who flatted.

Comment: I will read again.  OK I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Check on the flop you can put him on a draw
The board has a flush draw and runner runner straight draw
Top pair, 2 pair, or trips should bet 1/2 the pot to chase off draws

Turn hero bets 60% of the pot. You make your nut flush. Villain made quads.  What hand that you have beat is going to call?  Q high flush is not going to call.  2 pair is not going to call.  Trips might call.  Quad and full house will for sure call.  I think you should have checked.

Villain pushes on the river
You have to call 100 to win 130
You are getting 1.3:1
You are beat by 33, 55, JJ, TT, 35, T5, J5
Some are odd hands but hero has them or is bluffing
I think villain should have bet 2 times the pot so you could not lay down
Villain made it too easy for you to lay down by over betting
He would need to be bluffing 40% for that to be the correct call
That is just not a board to bluff
Based bet on the turn villain should put you on a flush or better
When I first read it I said heck yes got to call
But as I do the math fold seems like the way to go

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is a micro stake. So, rule no 1 - never assume players are good on that level.

Secondly, I assume you are playing online and if you use Poker Tracker you should see that players stats. If he is a very loose/fishy player or some kind of a maniac - then it is a call. If he plays solid hands and pretty tight - you can never call. Last card actually helps you - if he is not afraid of 4 diamonds and when he can never have A high or K high flushes - then the only hand he is representing is a full house.

Answer (score 0):

Villain is on the button!!!!!

He can not have a big hand on the flop and check in last position with a flush draw on the board (especially in a 3-handed pot).

If he has a big hand on the flop, he will start to build the pot with a bet in order to win a monster pot on the river.

You are beat by 33, 55, JJ, 35, J5 TT, T5,

The first four choices are unlikely for the reasons stated above.

T5???? raise on the button with an early limper????

**Not very likely.**

That leaves TT. If villain called with only 4 outs on the turn, you pretty much have to pay it off. (By the way, making a call which loses does not necessarily make it a **BAD** call.

Finally, with both the A and K of diamonds in your hand, your bet on the river is a bad one.

Check and make a crying call to a big bet. If you show weakness, the villain may not shove with a hand that beats you and let you off the hook with a smaller bet.

PLUS, the villain may make a moderate bluff on the river and you benefit in that alternative, also.